# 2-D Arrays in C/Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2-d array in my objective c project using regular c, but it is not working correctly.

First of all I declare this in my ViewController.h Interface file...

```
int selectedItemsInt;
```

That is the 2-d that I plan to use. Next I create the array in my onload method...

```
selectedItemsInt [36] [11] = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};
```

This is a huge 2-d array and I get two errors from it...

```
Expected expression &AND& Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
```

I would put an int in front of the array, but I want to access and edit the array further down in my code...

```
int index = selectedItemsInt [y][row]; //y and row are ints
```

and even with that code I get this same error...

```
Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `selectredItemsInt` as a two-dimensional array:

```
int selectedItemsInt [36] [11];
```

Then fill it up dynamically in the onload (unless you know the values at declaration time):

```
for (int i=0; i<36; ++i) {
  for (int j=0; j<11; ++j) {
    selectedItemsInt[i][j] = ...;
  }
}
```

If you know the values at declaration time, you can declare and initializa the array in one go:

```
int selectedItemsInt [36] [11] = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, ...};
```

Note that the first dimension here might be redundant: if you supply the correct number of initialization values, you can do this:

```
int selectedItemsInt [] [11] = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, ...};
```

If you supply both the dimension and list the values, but the number of listed values is less than the dimension declared, the end of the array will be uninitialized

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize it with this content, don't just declare it as int first:

```
int selectedItemsInt [36] [11] = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};
```

You declared `selectedItemsInt` as an `int`, and then when you thought you initialize the array, you actually tried to subscript an int (which is of course not allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is a strict superset of C. What works in C will work in Objective-C as well.

You are declaring the variable as a single int but then setting its content later on. Either set the content right away to declare it as a fixed size array of ints or declare it as a pointer to an int (that can be used as an array) `int *selectedItemsInt;`